# Project Euler 298 - there must be a correct answer? (only pastebinned code)

Tags: language-agnostic

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=298) has a paging file problem (though it's disguised in other words).

I tested [my code](http://paste-bin.com/view/ef8de9d4)(pastebinned so as not to spoil it for anyone) against the sample data and got the same memory contents+score as the problem. However, there is nowhere near a consistent grouping of scores. It asks for the expected difference in scores after 50 turns. A random sampling of scores:

```
1.50000000
1.78000000
1.64000000
1.64000000
1.80000000
2.02000000
2.06000000
1.56000000
1.66000000
2.04000000
```

I've tried a few of those as answers, but none of them have been accepted... I know *some* people have succeeded, so I'm really confused - what the heck am I missing?

Comment: A prime candidate for Monte-Carlo testing! You can even use this testing to keep it under the 1 minute rule, although as mentioned, I'm sure there is a formula to get the actual expected value. Also, `confused` is a tag? That's just awesome!

Comment: and *I* didn't even make it up ;) (though I think this is the first time I've really had a good excuse to use it!)

Comment: I don't think Monte-Carlo simulation will be a good idea to get 8 significant digits, IMHO that implies on the order of 10^16 runs of the simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem likely is that you don't seem to know the definition of [Expected Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

You will have to run the simulation multiple times and for each score difference, maintain the frequency of that occurence and then take the weighted mean to get the expected value.

Of course, given that it is Project Euler problem, there is probably a mathematical formula which can be used readily.

Comment: Is it irony that I felt like a moron and Moron answered my question? You're perfectly correct - I have never even heard of Expected Value. Curse you Project Euler and your mathematical terminology! Oh well, at least I learned *something* new today.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, there is a correct answer. To be honest, Monte Carlo can theoretically come close in on the expect value given the law of large numbers. However, you won't want to try it here. Because practically each time you run the simu, you will have a slightly different result rounded to eight decimal places (And I think this setting does exactly deprive anybody of any chance of even thinking to use Monte Carlo). If you are lucky, you will have one simu that delivers the answer after lots of trials, given that you have submitted all the previous and failed. I think, captcha is the second way that euler project let you give up any brute-force approach.

Well, agree with Moron, you have to figure out "expected value" first. The principle of this problem is, you have to find a way to enumerate every possible "essential" outcomes after 50 rounds. Each outcome will have its own |L-R|, so sum them up, you will have the answer. No need to say, brute-force approach fails in most of the case, especially in this case. Fortunately, we have dynamic programming (dp), which is fast!

Basically, dp saves the computation results in each round as states and uses them in the next. Thus it avoids repeating the same computation over and over again. The difficult part of this problem is to find a way to represent a state, that is to say, how you would like to save your temp results. If you have solved problem 290 in dp, you can get some hints there about how to understand the problem and formulate a state.

Actually, that isn't the most difficult part for the mind. The hardest mental piece is whether you realize that some memory statuses of the two players are numerically different but substantially equivalent. For example, L:12345 R:12345 vs L:23456 R:23456 or even vs L:98765 R:98765. That is due to the fact that the call is random. That is also why I wrote possible "essential" outcomes. That is, you can summarize some states into one. And only by doing so, your program can finish in reasonal time.

Answer (score 0):

I would run your simulation  a whole bunch of times and then do a weighted average of the `| L- R |` value over all the runs.  That should get you closer to the expected value.

Just submitting one run as an answer is really unlikely to work. Imagine it was dice roll expected value.  Roll on dice, score a 6, submit that as expected value.